# Python, if-else statement error

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import time
import random
print("Welcome to double up!")
pscore = 1
pscore = str(pscore)
print("Your current balance is "+pscore+", would you like to double or 
quit?")
while pscore != 0:
    pscore = str(pscore)
    print("Your current balance is "+pscore+"!")
    pscore = int(pscore)
    choice = input("d/q :")
    if choice == ("d")or("D"): #later simplify cases
        luck = random.randint(1,100)
        if luck > 75:
            print("Upgrade failed!")
            pscore = 0
        else:
            print("Upgrade complete!")
            pscore = pscore * 2
    else: #ERROR
        print("Incorrect command! Please retry!")
```

The  code line tagged with #ERROR doesn't run, no matter what I input as the variable 'choice' any help?

I would also welcome anything I can do to help cleanup my code, very new :p

https://pastebin.com/dPbpZfcy - The code as I messed up formatting on this site

Comment: It definitely shouldn't run. You have indentation errors.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well could you tell me where?

Comment: `if choice == ("d")or("D"): #later simplify cases` unindent this one level

Comment: @AyyLmao https://pastebin.com/j3PxKXLE

Comment: Don't convert pscore back and forth between an integer and string, just use str(pscore) when you need the string representation, no need to redefine the variable

Comment: I can't even get this to allow me to input something for the `choice` prompt. If I run the code exactly as-is, I get a SyntaxError on line 6. If I move `quit?")` so it's on the same line as the rest of the print statement, I get `IndentationError: unexpected indent` on line 12. If your code is executing up until the point where it asks you "d/q :", then it's not the same as the code you're showing us.

Comment: Once the indentation problem is fixed, this is probably a duplicate of [Why does `a == b or c or d` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/953482)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does \`a == b or c or d\` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems: one is that the line

```
if choice == ("d")or("D"): #later simplify cases
```

must be unindented. The second problem is that the if statement returns true if `choice == ("d")` **or** if `("D")`, the second of which is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Unindent the `if choice ...` line by one level. Then, change the if statement to say this:

```
if choice in ('d', 'D'):
```

What you had previously will always evaluate to true and the `else` will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if choice == ("d")or("D"): #later simplify cases` line have the wrong identation.

Comment: The indentation is a problem, but it isn't the only problem. And the indentation problem probably isn't even present in the OP's original code, or else it would flat-out fail to run entirely, rather than execute but never execute the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Unindent this line:

```
if choice == ("d")or("D"): #later simplify cases
```

Comment: don't know why you were downvoted, thats correct.

Comment: The indentation is a problem, but it isn't the only problem. And the indentation problem probably isn't even present in the OP's original code, or else it would flat-out fail to run entirely, rather than execute but never execute the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# import time - Unused. you can remove this line
import random
print("Welcome to double up!")
pscore = 1
pscore = str(pscore)
print("Your current balance is "+pscore+", would you like to double or quit?")
while pscore != 0:
    pscore = str(pscore)
    print("Your current balance is "+pscore+"!")
    pscore = int(pscore)
    choice = input("d/q :")
    if choice == ("d")or("D"): #later simplify cases   # <<< Indent here.
        luck = random.randint(1,100)
        if luck > 75:
            print("Upgrade failed!")
            pscore = 0
        else:
            print("Upgrade complete!")
            pscore = pscore * 2
    else: #ERROR
        print("Incorrect command! Please retry!")
```